# creating my own save command in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

As we all know that cakephp has default save command for inserting record into the database.
But i want to know can i create my own save command in cakephp or modify the existing one.
Can I do this?

You must be asking why i'm asking why i'm saying that? let me give you an live example for this----
Suppose i have an textbox which contains the username entered by the user.I'm not taking this as unique, hence more than one user will insert same username(possible..).

Ex-My name is prakash Gupta and i'm taking the username 'prakash'. There will be other users also whose name can be prakash gupta and they will provide the same username.Now inorder to solve this i'm using random function and attaching some digits behind the username, so that
it will be different for every one.
 Now 'save' command will take the username which i entered in the textbox and insert into the database but i want to insert the modified username into the database which i generated
by random function. can this be possible??? 
if yes let me know....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you don't change the standard one but either add another one or use the beforeSave etc. hooks.

The save functions are part of the Models. Normally you modify them with: Behaviors. See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html They let you modify the models, saving etc. without having to code all directly into your models.

*Based on your edit:*

**Unique constraint**

As I see you want a unique username. There are multiple solutions for that. First make sure to set a constraint. Even your random() trick will possibly generate a duplicate since random can create also the same. So username.random(4) could generate multiple times: username1234. You cannot be sure.

Constraints should be set at for example your model level. Start this unique check with validations of CakePHP.

**When do you know the username is already used**

You will know when the validation failed. So first just validate the record. So before save call model::validate() to check whether your unique constraint is ok. If yes just save.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

If not you can add your random string and check again. Call model::validate to see if it is now ok. This part could be implemented for example in a behaviour in the beforeSave() method.

Now you have a unique one save your record. Make sure to check whether it succeeded because it is possible that in the meantime another record with that username was added. In that case re-run the process.

**Lots of work**

It is hard because multiple clients can add data same time in a database before you even know. Most simple is to catch the error, so just call save with your username. If it fails because of your unique constraint add the random() string and try again and again. It should be possible to save. Trick here with your random string because if it is short and a username is used a lot you can run into issues. If your random string is 3 numbers you can have the same username 1000 times, from 000 to 999.

**Other option**

What you sometimes see is suggestions, the interface suggests some free names based on your username input. You still need the check though.

**Another option**
Just tell the user it is in use. Maybe add an ajax check so you can instantly show the result by validating the field.

Comment: ok thanks but i am new to cakephp and don't have so much idea about it. started it 5 days back. thnaks for ur response.